# CUDA GPU Integer/Float Size Constraint

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

This is a very simple question, but have not been able to find a good answer for it anywhere. What is the size constraint for the float type on the GPU. For example, I need to cube many large numbers say 3,000,000,000 ^ 3. When I get my result set back from the GPU I get something nonsensical, a large negative number. My guess is that this is how overflow is handled. Any explanation and comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Calculate it yourself, as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812422/how-to-find-epsilon-min-and-max-constants-for-cuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float` on the GPU has the same numerical capacity and precision as `float` on the host, using the host compiler.  [It has](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_formats) 23 mantissa bits, 8 exponent bits, and one sign bit.   The binary exponent range spans from -126 to +127 which corresponds to a decimal exponent range of about +/- 37  (127/log2(10))

Since your example of `3,000,000,000 ^ 3` should yield a number with a positive decimal exponent of about 28, it should not "overflow" the basic `float` storage capacity.

`int` on the GPU likewise is the same 32-bit signed quantity that is represented by `int` on the host/host compiler.  Since it is a signed number, it can store numbers up to approximately +/- 2,147,483,640

You would be in trouble right from the start if you are handling your example using `int`.  That number will not fit in `int` representation, even before you cube it.

If you are using `float`, you might want to inspect your code for other data handling issues that are leading to these kinds of unexpected results, or else post a small sample reproducer, consistent with the expectations at SSCCE.org.   Of course if you are interpreting `float` as `int` or vice-versa, you will get strange results.

Comment: This is the answer for which I was looking. The trouble is that I am using CUDAfy.NET, so I will need to dig a bit to see if there is a bug in the project.

Comment: Quite simply the problem originated in the passing the variable to the function. In .NET when one does not specify `float a = 3000000000F;` vs. `float a = 3000000000;` .NET will take the liberty of "casting" the assigned number to a double. Good to know.

Comment: Actually C also [defines constants this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9bk1wcy(v=vs.90).aspx).  `30.0` is a `double` constant in C.  `30.0f` is a `float` constant in C.  It's not clear to me why this would make a difference.  Either `float` or `double` can represent this number, as well as the cubed result.  Possibly when you do `float a = 3000000000;` you end up with a constant that is niether `float` nor `double`, since you have left out the decimal point.  If you do `float a = 3000000000.0;` I think it will also work correctly.